# PHP More Secure Way To Redirect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php page which does an insert and then does a redirect to a "success" page which displays the order details.  I am redirecting by using a variable, but I am thinking this is not so secure:

`header("location:success.php?id=$orderid");`

This generates a url like this: `success.php?id=22`

I am then using the URL to obtain the order ID number and doing a query based off of that to present the order details:

```
$getName = explode('?id=', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$id = $getName[1];

$query = <<<SQL
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `orderid` = ?;
SQL;

$request = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$request->bind_param("i", $id);
$request->execute();
```

The obvious issue is that anyone could simply change the URL id number to get the details of a different order number.  I'm not too terribly concerned as this is strictly an internal site, but I'd still like to fix this behavior.  Is there a better, more secure way to do this?

Comment: Use an indexed column where you store a `uniqid()` and submit this uniqid with your link. This way you can not just guess other order numbers.

Comment: I would assume that the user is logged in, so you can check for both the order ID and de user ID from the session.

Comment: The orderid is the unique column in my table (it auto increments each time a new row is inserted).  So I should generate a new column and make that one unique (and obviously not match the orderid), and use that instead?  EDIT:  The user is not logged in.  I was going to make a different page that allows the end-user to view their order by having to input their email address.  But this page is the page directly after the end-user submits the order.

Comment: Sessions are your friend here, especially if you've already taken steps to authenticate the session data (which you should).

Log the order ID to the session, and then clear it once you've finished with the information.

Comment: You can do a "order tocken" in your database. So to access to this order you have to insert the tocken. If you inserted the "username" who do this order, you have two auth methods that are not exclusive, so you can use both.

Comment: If the user is logged in, then validate that a) the order number exists and b) the order is associated with the user accessing it.  If the user is not logged in, then create a random token that is unique to every order and use that as the identifier instead of a simple integer.

Comment: I would recommend what @jeroen said.  Any other method is just suggesting the same thing in a different manor.  Ultimately your need to associate an order with an owner.  And that owner should be forced to authenticate with the order.  If you want anonymous orders, then I'd have another table with a unique hash and the order id, so the URL params would need both the order ID and this unique hash.  It help keep scripts from just trying different IDs all day. Of course your anon user would need to save this hash somewhere themselves.  Usually a confirmation email containing the link would work.

Comment: Thanks all.  Looks like session is the best answer here for my needs, but will research all options given.

Comment: I would add a "AND user_id = [current user id]" clause, so that all logic still remains the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an easier solution: Store orderid in the session like this `$_SESSION['orderid'] = $orderid`.

And on redirect you'll get it's value as below:

```
$getName = explode('?id=', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$id = $_SESSION['orderid'];

$query = <<<SQL
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `orderid` = ?;
SQL;

$request = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$request->bind_param("i", $id);
$request->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Imran - was about to post that I ended up using a solution like this as it appeared to be the simplest way to go about it.  I will mark your answer since it is the one that works for my needs.  I may later on decide to make another unique ID column to further obscure things, but for the time being this will suffice.

Comment: Welcome you can always do that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the problem of allowing a customer to view a past order while not allowing others to view this order has two steps.

1. Set authorization policy: Determine which users are allowed to view which order numbers. This ought to include the ability to come back in a later session and view the status of an order.
2. Back it with an authentication method: Store and retrieve enough information to identify the user.

Authorization policies to consider include the following:

1. The user who just placed an order is allowed to view it in the same session. This is the policy you describe in your question.
2. Placing an order creates a unique ID. Anyone with this ID is allowed to view it.
3. Someone who creates a user account, provides an e-mail address and verifies ability to receive mail at that address is allowed to list orders associated with that billing e-mail and view them.
4. Someone who provides the correct order ID and shipping postal code (or other PII needed for order processing) is allowed to view that order, but not list any, and this is rate limited in some manner for each IP address. (Users behind a big NAT have the other three choices.)

To implement policy 1 (same session), you can store the order ID in the session, whether in PHP's `$_SESSION` or in a separate session properties table, as soon as the order is marked as paid.  Then when the user tries to view an order, you can allow it if the order ID matches the most recent for this session.

To implement policy 2 (unique ID), you can generate and store a suitably long random identifier, such as a [version 4 UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29), and store it with the order. Warn the user: "Be careful: anyone who sees this order ID can view and change your order."

To implement policies 1 and 2 in one stroke, you can store the session ID with each order, display the session ID on the success page, and then let the user search for orders associated with a particular session.

To implement policy 3 (control of billing e-mail), you can add a user table including user ID, password hash, e-mail address, and (nullable) e-mail confirmation date. This would also give you a chance to add user-created product lists, which lets you add features such as an alert when a product comes back in stock.

To implement policy 4 (order ID and shipping info), you can make a table logging the IP address, date, and more information about each request, apply a heuristic to determine whether a scripted brute force attack is in progress, and then compare the shipping postal code provided by the user to that in the order.

Keep these policies and mechanisms in mind as you continue to develop your store application, as they are likely to increase its usability.

Answer (score -1):

On your system I **assumed** your orders are related to you users.

For example order: 1234 has relation with user: 5

Check this relation on your success.php

If your scheme has not user-order relation I strongly recommend it. But if orders doing by anon users, hash order_id

basically like

```
select * from order where order_id = 1234 and userid =5
```

**If this query returns a row, that user really has this order.** Else something is wrong.

```
if($returnedRow == 1){
 //Do something here
}else{
 //access denied. You are not owner of this order.
}
```

As I said, count returned row, this is simple way. Also if you hash your order_id like dfljfk45498ds545 it can be less predictable. You can use **[uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.uniqid.php)** for this purpose.

Comment: I just assumed. If he has not users, he can use only uniqid ids

Comment: Personally i think you should update the answer to suggest he correlate the users and the orders.. That would be a slight improvement on his current method.

Comment: The answer not complete and is based on assumptions as well. Further explanation required.

Answer (score -3):

use cookie or session to send `"$orderid"`
*session is better

Comment: What ? Why is it better ?